# Set A Connection String In Excel To A Cell Value

Tags: excel

I'm creating a workbook for some folks to be able to manipulate some data, get blessings from all involved, then hand off to someone else to manually enter back into the system... Don't ask, we are afraid of scripting back to the system.

I am attempting to do this in the Data Connections Properties Window.

Data > Connections > Properties > Definition (I can't attach a screen shot cause I'm a noob I guess)

I have many different work arounds. I have even created a VB script that will do this, allow users to change server targets, pass different security credentials, but, just this last Monday there was some kind of office patch that screwed up all activeX and I had to go wipe out a temp file to correct it. I can't do that with a bunch of users that are less than tech savvy that are geographically separated, I don't have RDP authority.

For example, the connection string currently looks like:

```
DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};
System=myserver.network.net;
```

I was hoping to set it to look like:

```
DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};
System="Overview!D9";
```

The cell, Overview!D9, could then be changed by who ever to the correct system string, like myserver.network.net or server1.network.net.

Near as I can tell from my research, the connection properties window is pretty cut and dry and this might not be possible. But figured I would ask around.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `System` is just a string, then getting the value is simple.

```
' Assuming System is a String
Dim System As String
System = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overview").Range("D9").Value
```

If `System` is part of another string, its much the same

```
' Get the value to use in the connection string
Dim System As String
System = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overview").Range("D9").Value

Dim ConnectionString As String
ConnectionString = "DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver}; SYSTEM=" & System & ";"
```

If security is a problem, and your people generating/manipulating the data don't NEED the macros to do their work (ie, just the person entering the data back into the system does) then you don't need to put the macros in their workbooks.

You can add your macro's to the "Default Workbook" on the data entry person's computer. These macros will then be available to all workbooks they open on their computer.

Your data entry person gets the benefit of scripted automation and your users don't have to worry about email or anti-virus problems.

Comment: That's the standard connection information in VB, I was hoping to do this in the connection properties window. ActiveX is easy to break with all the SOX, HIPPA, PCI, LMNOP security measures running amuck.

Comment: @Carl did you ever figure out how to pull this off in the connection properties window?